# order changed event in jquery sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Now i'm using jQuery library and i faced the folowing problem:
Supppose i have the sortable list if items

```
    <html>
       <head>
         <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
         <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js>  </script>
         <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
       <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
                jQuery(".block").sortable({
                axis: 'y'
             });
          });
      </script>

      </head>
      <body>
          <ul class="block" type="none">
               <li>1</li>
               <li>2</li>
               <li>3</li>
          </ul>
      </body>
  </html>
```

So ofter order changed, how can i make listener for this event, i mean ,is there any listener for order changed event or something like this.

Comment: Ya! there is check the documentation of jquery ui sortable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's right there in the documentation. Use the [`change`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#event-change) or [`update`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#event-update) event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".block").sortable({
        axis: 'y',
        change: function(event, ui) { 
            console.log('change', event, ui); 
        },
        update: function(event, ui) {
            console.log('update', event, ui); 
        }
    });
});
```

Also either use `jQuery` or `$`, don't mix them.

Comment: I think [`update`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#event-update) may fit better for OP's needs as well: `This event is triggered when the user stopped sorting and the DOM position has changed.`.

Comment: sortable divs on draging now start blinking and vibrating with this script - everything lags. Is there any better decision to catch an event, nut just on every milisecond when any sortable div is moving?

Answer (score 2):

Yes,

```
$( ".selector" ).bind( "sort", function(event, ui) {
    ...
});
```

Directly from the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#event-sort).

Comment: my new mantra , "read documentation before asking questions", thanks a lot